# Jenkins on Windows Server - how to connect to VPN

Tags: jenkins, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a VPN on a Windows Server that I need to connect to via Jenkins that runs on this Windows Server 2012.

Should I use RasDial?

Should I use [VPN Client Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell](http://VPN%20Client%20Cmdlets%20in%20Windows%20PowerShell) ? I cannot see how to connect via this page - there are various other commands.

Any advice please?